# Does CANBus need encryption?

Tags: encryption, can-bus

I realized there is no encryption in CANBus communication. So my question is: Does it worth to add an encryption method to CANBus communication in a vehicle. Since the communication takes place between the ECU's in the same vehicle, I believe CANBus is safe against the remote attacks/attackers. So I think encryption is not necesssary. However, putting an encryption in CANBus might make it harder to make your vehicle get reverse engineered. Am I correct? To sum up, I have 3 questions:

1. Does CANBus needs an encryption method and does adding it worth to effort?
2. If yes what kind of encryption method would be the best for the CANBus communication in a vehicle?
3. Does adding an encryption to CANBus in your vehicled, would make it harder to get reverse engineered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not really. Depends what you want to protect against. To prevent a car thief from hacking into your CAN bus, use the usual protection measures against thieves: locks and alarms.

   A couple of horrible car designs connect a MCU on the bus to the Internet for firmware updates. If you do that, you risk getting it hacked remotely, if an attacker can figure out how to download their own firmware into that MCU. Jeep had some design flaw like that iirc. But the design flaw is not of the CAN bus itself, it is the provided internet access to a MCU which also has access to the bus.
2. I suppose whatever is currently regarded as safe. But if it involves a lot of heavy math, it might be unsuitable for that purpose, since these are hard real-time systems, often with low end, decentralized CPUs. They won't be able to do heavy floating point math fast enough.
3. Of course.

Comment: So if it was a military vehicle. Would we need some kind of safety measurement? And can an attacker hijack your vehicle or damage it by your radio channel? Or maybe from GPS?

Comment: But let's think about an radio ECU. That is open to distant communication. (Not like the other ECU's only communicating inside the vehicle.such engine ECU.) In this case, attacker can reach the radio ECU then can move on to the other ECU's. Isn't it possible?